# How do I divide 2 floats in Swift?

Tags: swift, floating-point, swift3

I'm getting the errors

`Col 60: binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'Float' operands`

`Expected an argument list of type '(Double, Double)' (line 62, col 60)`

I don't see why I cannot divide the two numbers. I'm working on a project that requires me to run these calculations using single precision values, so I *need* to use `Float` here.

**The code:**

```
func logC(val: Double, forBase base: Double) -> Float {
    return Float(log(val)/log(base))
}

logC(val: abs((sum1(N: 12100)-sum3(N: 12100))/sum3(N: 12100) ), forBase: 10)
```

**What I've tried:**

1. Casting the result to `Float`
2. Casting each parameter in the calculation to `Float`

Comment: It's also a dupe of [many other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+binary+operator+cannot+be+applied+to+two+operands). Please always search on an error before posting.

Comment: That question didn't help and searching through other questions didn't either.

Comment: Then you didn't actually read and understand my answer to the duplicate. It's the same basic problem.

Comment: You want the result to be a Double so the two operands must also be two Doubles.

Comment: I do not want the results to be a Double.

Comment: The goal here is to write a program using single precision values in order to learn more about them. I do not want int or double values.

Comment: Then why is the return type of your function Double?

Comment: Oh, that's a mistake. I'll update.

Comment: You still have a mix of types. Why are the parameters of type `Double` if you want `Float`?

Comment: Ah, that was it. Thanks!